# Flask-Admin: Setting up a Custom View that's configurable from config.py

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm creating a document repository using Flask and Flask-Admin.

#### The problem:

How do I dynamically set the base_path in the Document View to use a variable from my config file? Currently I'm using `current_app` and I'm getting the `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

Depending on whether I'm using my test, dev or prod config I'd like to use a different path, which I'd ideally configure in the appropriate class in config.py. Is there a way to do this without pushing the app context from my Document View?

Here's my class in admin.py:

```
class DocumentView(CustomView):
    # Override form field to use Flask-Admin FileUploadField
    form_overrides = {
        'path': form.FileUploadField
    }

    # Pass additional parameters to 'path' to FileUploadField constructor
    form_args = {
        'path': {
            'label': 'File',
            'base_path': current_app.config['DOCUMENT_REPO'],
            'allow_overwrite': True
        }
    }
```

and my class in config.py:

```
class DevConfig(Config):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///database.db'
    DEBUG = True
    DEBUG_TB_INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS = False
    CACHE_TYPE = 'simple'
    CACHE_NO_NULL_WARNING = True
    DOCUMENT_REPO = #path
```

#### Update:

I tried pulling the form_args into a method and setting it `before_first_request` which solved my application context issue. However the now I'm getting `ValueError: FileUploadField field requires base_path to be set.` when I add a file.

method in the create_app function:

```
@app.before_first_request
def add_context_to_admin():
    admin.add_link(MenuLink(name='Main', url=url_for('main.home')))
    admin.add_link(MenuLink(name='Logout', url=url_for('main.logout')))

    view = DocumentView(
        Document,
        db.session,
        name='Documents'
    )

    view.init_form_args(current_app)

    admin.add_view(
        view
    )
```

and the refactored class in admin.py:

```
class DocumentView(CustomView):

    # Override form field to use Flask-Admin FileUploadField
    form_overrides = {
        'path': form.FileUploadField
    }

    # Pass additional parameters to 'path' to FileUploadField constructor
    def init_form_args(self, app):
        self.form_args = {
            'path': {
                'label': 'File',
                'base_path':  app.config['DOCUMENT_REPO'],
                'allow_overwrite': True
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being to override init in the the DocumentView subclass and initialize it `before_first_request`.

Method in create_app:

```
@app.before_first_request
def add_context_to_admin():
    admin.add_link(MenuLink(name='Main', url=url_for('main.home')))
    admin.add_link(MenuLink(name='Logout', url=url_for('main.logout')))

    admin.add_view(
        DocumentView(
            current_app,
            Document,
            db.session,
            name='Documents'
        )
    )
```

Class in admin.py:

```
class DocumentView(CustomView):

    def __init__(self, app, model, session, name=None, category=None, endpoint=None, url=None, static_folder=None,
                 menu_class_name=None, menu_icon_type=None, menu_icon_value=None):

        # Override form field to use Flask-Admin FileUploadField
        self.form_args = {
            'path': {
                'label': 'File',
                'base_path':  app.config['DOCUMENT_REPO'],
                'allow_overwrite': True
            }
        }

        super().__init__(model, session, name, category, endpoint, url, static_folder, menu_class_name,
                         menu_icon_type, menu_icon_value)

    form_overrides = {
        'path': form.FileUploadField
    }
```